# TypeORM: bulk insert with unnest

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, query-builder, unnest

I'm trying to do a bulk insert with TypeORM query builder using postgres `unnest` function.

Code sample:

```js
manager
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .insert()
  .into(Foo)
  .values(qb =>
    qb.select('*').from('UNNEST($1::int[], $2::text[], $3::text[])', [data1, data2, data3])),
  )
```

This doesn't work and generates this query:

```sql
INSERT INTO "foo"("a", "b", "c") VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

Any idea how to make it work without having to use a raw query?

Comment: It appears like each of your parameters are themselves an array. However the unnest function applies to *a single array*. So you may need to unest each. Something like `'unnest($1::int[]), unnest($2::text[]), unnest($3::text[])', [data1, data2, data3]))...` but I do not know your obfuscation layer (Typeorm). See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=20faa8f1d407d58fcba148ae6eee942e) here for Postgres implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the issue is with Typeorm not the query itself which works. :)